# shall I use state management to store map markers?

Tags: javascript, redux, vuex

I need your opinion on this. I will try to quickly explain this.

- I have one page. called Parent component.

  That page has 4 tabs.    So that page has 4 same children
  component, but different instances

  Each tab needs to have its own data to show on the map, so I grab
  all of the data in Parent, and pass appropriate portions to each
  children component's.

  Each children component also has 3 tabs.Let's say we are on the first tab. And I clicked again on of the 3    tabs. Some markers 
  should be removed. Then Clicked the previous tab. Some markers have to be added. and so on.

**Is this a good idea?** I was thinking of storing marker objects in state management. So that when moving to one tab from another, I'd have state already so no need to create data. I'd simply loop through markers from store. What if my markers array grow to 100,000. it means I'd have kind of 400,000 objects in store. Is this a good practice to store such large data in store?

Comment: The parent component should not know anything about it‘s children data, but should only be notified respectively get data via @output from it‘s children. In this way the parent storage (array, map, localStorage etc.) does not become very big and complex and...it would take more time to fetch and update certain chunks of data as well. Therefore keeping the data only within it‘s children contributes to a better performance and less complex code at least in the parent component.